# Markov chain discrete-time queue example

Tags: markov-process

I have the following Markov chain example:

> Items arrive for processing during intervals $(0, 1), (1, 2), \dots$
>
> $A_n$ is the number of arrivals during $(n - 1, n), n = 1, 2, \dots$
>
> Assume the $A_n$ are i.i.d. with pmf $a_j = P(A_n = j), j = 0, 1, \dots$
>
> Let $$b_i = P(A_n \ge i) = \sum_{j \ge i} a_j .$$
>
> Arriving items queue in order of arrival in a buffer with capacity $K \ge 1$, with arbitrary ordering for simultaneous arrivals.
>
> Arrivals to a full buffer are lost.
>
> A single server dispatches one item at a time $n$, if any are waiting.
>
> Let $X_n$ denote the buffer level at time $n$, just before dispatch.
>
> $S = \{ 0, 1, \dots, K \}$
>
> **Checking the Markov property**
>
> If $X_n = 0$, there is no dispatch at $n$, and the number in the buffer at time $n + 1$ is the number of arrivals during $(n, n + 1)$ that can fit into the buffer.
>
> i.e., $X_{n + 1} = \min(A_{n + 1}, K)$

I don't understand how it makes sense to have $X_{n + 1} = \min(A_{n + 1}, K)$. I would greatly appreciate it if someone would please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an analogous, less contrived, version of this example (in fact, based on the completeness and coherency of the example, it's probably the original version) from the textbook *Introduction to Modeling and Analysis of Stochastic Systems*, second edition, by Kulkarni:

> *Example 2.8.* (Telecommunications). The Tel-All Switch Corporation manufactures switching equipment for communications networks. Communication networks move data from switch to switch at lightning-fast speed in the form of packets; i.e., strings of zeros and ones (called bits). The Tel-All switches handle data packets of constant length; i.e., the same number of bits in each packet. At a conceptual level, we can think of the switch as a storage device where packets arrive from network users according to a random process. They are stored in a buffer with the capacity to store $K$ packets and are removed from the buffer one-by-one according to a pre-specified protocol. Under one such protocol, time is slotted into intervals of fixed length, say a microsecond. If there is a packet in the buffer at the beginning of a slot, it is removed instantaneously. If there is no packet at the beginning of a slot, no packet is removed during the slot even if more packets arrive during the slot. If a packet arrives during a slot and there is no space for it, it is discarded. Model this as a DTMC.
>
> Let $A_n$ be the number of packets that arrive at the switch during the $n$th slot. (Some of these may be discarded.) Let $X_n$ be the number of packets in the buffer at the end of the $n$th slot. Now, if $X_n = 0$, then there are no packets available for transmission at the beginning of the $(n + 1)$st slot. Hence all the packets that arrive during that slot, namely $A_{n + 1}$, are in the buffer at the end of that slot unless $A_{n + 1} > K$, in which case the buffer is full at the end of the $(n + 1)$st slot. Hence $X_{n + 1} = \min\{ A_{n + 1}, K \}$. If $X_n > 0$, one packet is removed at the beginning of the $(n + 1)$st slot and $A_{n + 1} packets are added during that slow, subject to capacity limitations. Combining these cases, we get
>
> $$X_{n + 1} = \begin{cases} \min\{ A_{n + 1}, K \} & \text{if} \ X_n = 0,
> \\ \min\{ X_n + A_{n + 1} - 1, K \} & \text{if} \ 0 < X_n \le K. \end{cases}$$
>
> Assume that $\{ A_n, n \ge 1 \}$ is a sequence of iid random variables with common pdf
>
> $$P(A_n = k) = a_k, k \ge 0.$$
>
> Under this assumption, $\{ X_n, n \ge 0 \}$ is a DTMC on state space $\{ 0, 1, 2, \dots, K \}$. The transition probabilities can be computed as follows. For $0 \le j < K$,
>
> $$\begin{align} P(X_{n + 1} = j \vert X_n = 0) &= P(\min\{ A_{n + 1}, K \} = j \vert X_n = 0) \\ &= P(A_{n + 1} = j) \\ &= a_j \end{align}$$
>
> $$\begin{align} P(X_{n + 1} = K \vert X_n = 0) &= P(\min\{A_{n + 1}, K \} = K \vert X_n = 0) \\ &= P(A_{n + 1} \ge K) \\ &= \sum_{k = K}^\infty a_k. \end{align}$$
>
> Similarly, for $1 \le i \le K$ and $i - 1 \le j < K$,
>
> $$\begin{align} P(X_{n + 1} = j \vert X_n = i) &= P(\min\{X_n + A_{n + 1} - 1, K \} = j \vert X_n = i) \\ &= P(A_{n + 1} = j - i + 1) \\ &= a_{j - 1 + 1}. \end{align}$$
>
> Finally, for $1 \le i \le K$,
>
> $$\begin{align} P(X_{n + 1} = K \vert X_n = i) &= P(\min\{ X_n + A_{n + 1} - 1, K \} = K \vert X_n = i) \\ &= P(A_{n + 1} \ge K - i + 1) \\ &= \sum_{k = K - i + 1}^\infty a_k . \end{align}$$
>
> Combining all these cases and using the notation
>
> $$b_j = \sum_{k = j}^\infty a_k,$$
>
> we get the transition probability matrix
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix} a_0 & a_1 & \dots & a_{K - 1} & b_K \\ a_0 & a_1 & \dots & a_{K - 1} & b_K \\ 0 & a_0 & \dots & a_{K - 2} & b_{K - 1} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & a_0 & b_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

This property is a formula that says: "Arrivals to a full buffer are lost". However, there seems to be something missing here to make everything correct, it seems to me that this should read,

$$
X_{n+1} = \text{min}\left(X_{n} + A_{n+1}, K\right)
$$

That is, the number of items at time `n+1` equals the previous number of items plus the number of arrivals, or the maximum capacity if that's smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think your are incorrect. See my answer.

Comment: Right, I didnt' read correctly, but if you assume $X_n$ equals zero, but then the formulas are equivalent. Except for the minus one, which appears in the second example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway